# Planck Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-gravity

I have heard of two different things occurring at Planck Temperature:
1. A black hole forms
2. The quantum gravity takes over and the wavelength of light emitted from the object is Planck length

Which is correct? Are both correct? Are neither correct?

Comment: I read that when objects become this hot they have sufficient kinetic energy to collide and produce noticeable quantum gravity which in this case a tiny black hole that will perhaps prevent photons with Planck length from being emitted, that's sound preposterous and could be wrong.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have a feeling that you can help.

Comment: (Hint: If I haven't commented, that doesn't ping me) I'm not sure, but I *think* the correct answer is: There's a lot of speculation, but there is no universally accepted *specific* thing that happens that the Planck scales - the only thing we know for sure is our *current* theories break down there.